Change the installation path of phpmyadmin
I have installed a web server (Apache, PHP, Maria-DB, phpMyAdmin) from the Debian packages.
Now I would like to hide the installation of phpMyAdmin, i.e. the call via "https://hostname/phpmyadmin" should no longer be possible. My idea is to rename the folder so that it can only be accessed via "https://hostname/geheimer_Ordnername".
Is it enough to simply rename the folder name ... or am I being too naive here? :)
I haven't done anything yet because I don't want to make any mistakes out of ignorance.

Debian uses a custom configuration file, /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf to handle all of this, so you can edit that file to change the Alias statement. Changing the folder name on the disk won't be sufficient because the Alias is what really configures what URL path Apache responds to.
